# Is it possible to sell a patent that already has been in production?

Tags: sellpatent

I hold a current Utlity Patent on a children’s product with 8 years left before expiring. How do you go about selling? Thanks Lisa

Comment: I’m afraid licensing questions are off topic for this site.

Comment: By the way, I looked up your name in Google Patents and found only one design patent (USD688442S1). Design Patents are not the same as Utility patents. Is the patent inventor someone else?